# $.parseJSON error: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, string, parsing

I build an array with jQuery then stringify it for saving in a DB with PHP through a hidden input element:

```
var dataObject = [];
dataObject.push({
    text: text
});
var dataObjectString = JSON.stringify(dataObject);
$('#data').val(dataObjectString);
```

In PHP I convert it to Base64 before saving in a DB:

```
$args['data'] = isset($args['data']) ? base64_encode($args['data']) : '';
```

For view I decode it from Base64 and set the string:

```
$this->set('js_data', base64_decode($this->data));
```

In the view itself I put that in a div attribute and then read it with jQuery:

```
<div class="my_class" data-js="'<?php echo h($js_data); ?>'">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
$(function(){
    $.each($('.my_class[data-js]'), function(index, element){
        var js_data = $(element).attr('data-js');
        init(element, js_data);
    });

    function init(element, js_data) {
        console.log(js_data);
    };
});
</script>
```

So far so good, I have the string printed in the console. But that's just a string. I need a json object in order to read my initial array values. So If I do

```
$.parseJSON($(element).attr('data-js'));
```

it throws an error: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". Why? How else can I convert the string to json?

Comment: *"In PHP I convert it to Base64 before saving in a DB"*  - uhh, why? Except for making the string 1/3 longer, what good does that do?

Comment: What's `h()`? A shortcut to `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: I read it's good practice to store long text as base64 instead of plain text

Comment: yes, h() is short for htmlspecialchars()

Comment: Forget what you have heard there, that's bollocks. Base64 is for storing *binary* data in a text column (or in a text file, or in JSON, or in XML, etc). If you have a string, just store it in the database column directly. Make sure your DB is set to UTF-8 and cut out that superfluous base64-part. If your DB supports it, use a dedicated JSON data type - [MySQL has one](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html), for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> yes, `h()` is short for `htmlspecialchars()`

`htmlspecialchars()` escapes double quotes as `&quot;`. This is enough, it's wrong to enclose the attribute value in an extra pair of single quotes.

This should work.

```
<div class="my_class" data-js="<?php echo h($js_data); ?>">
```

Comment: Of course! Those stupid single quotes... I pasted some of the code from php and then forgot to delete the single quotes. It works now. Thank you very much!